# Reach heroku app terminal

Tags: heroku, terminal

I deployed an app onto heroku and wanted to check how can I connect to the deployed app in my terminal so I can do things like run migrations?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `heroku` command to create a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) to run arbitrary commands like `bash` or `rake db:migrate`.

For example `heroku run bash -a my-app` will run a bash shell on a one-off dyno.

Note that there is no way to directly connect to a running dyno on Heroku (e.g. via ssh); running the `heroku run` command will create a new temporary dyno that you can use to run commands using the deployed version of the code.